truffle console doesnt work: Unexpected error setting up the environment or provisioning contracts while instantiating the console
(base) ➜  METoken truffle console                 

bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)
Unexpected error setting up the environment or provisioning contracts while instantiating the console.
Error: Error parsing or reading ERC20.json: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/console.js:301:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Console.provision (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/console.js:268:1)
    at Console.start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/console.js:142:1)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at Object.module.exports [as run] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/console/run.js:23:1)
    at runCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command-utils.js:297:1)


truffle version: v5.11.5
solidity: 0.4.24

Truffle has been deprecated. It will be better if you look for a replacement like hardhat or foundry.

i uninstalled truffle and install truffle of 4.x.x； It worked!
